# Is this grammar LR(1)?

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, grammar, context-free-grammar, lr-grammar

A bit confused about whether this grammar is ambiguous or not

```
C' -> C
C -> d C u C
C -> d C
C -> ε
```

I tried building the DFA for this but I get this in one of the states:

```
C -> d C DOT u C, $
C -> d C DOT, $
```

Isn't this a shift-reduce conflict, so surely it means the grammar is not LR(1)? Or does it reduce regardless since $ and u are both in the follow set of C?

Comment: This question belongs on cs.stackexchange.com

Comment: If you write compilers, this is a perfectly good programming question.

Comment: I agree with Gene.  The analogous programming question is,  "I've examined my code.  I see a place that looks suspicious.  Can I get a subscript error there, or is there a rule I should know that prevents it?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does have a shift-reduce conflict. Here's the state machine produced by selecting shift. The conflict is in state 4. [image: state machine]

I should point out that your question is a bit off. A grammar can be unambiguous and still not LR(1).

But this one happens to be provably ambiguous. Consider the string `ddudu`.  Two leftmost derivations are

```
C'->C->dCuC->ddCuCuC->dduCuC->ddudCuC->dduduC->ddudu
C'->C->dCuC->ddCuC->dduC->ddudCuC->dduduC->ddudu
```

The existence of these says the grammar is ambiguous.

Proving a general grammar ambiguous is an undecidable problem: there can be no algorithm for it. Happily this one is not so hard to sort out.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what did you use to generate the graph?

Comment: bison to generate a vcg file and yComp to draw it.